# Make MSW 8 x86 bootable HDD Installer from ISO Installer

Tags: windows-8, boot, iso-image, installer

I have seek for several sites about installing Microsoft Windows 8 directly from a HDD, with no positive results.

[This site](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-CLEAN-Install-Windows-8-directly-from-Hard-/), for some reason, don't works.

Most of them at some step require a CD or Floppy unit, which I don't have either.

I have also not found good alternatives for Linux either. Most if not all involve using a Floppy.

This is a very old (32 bit, x86) PC without CD, Floppy or USB BIOS support, and instead of just throwing it into the trash, i wish to leave it functional before passing it into beneficence.

How should I make a bootable HDD installer, from a bootable ISO installer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A Ubuntu USB stick installer will boot fine if `dd`'ed onto a HDD

Comment: I think using an ISO image installation is an easy way to do this. But if you don't have a ISO, you need to copy it from other machine, so you could install it from HDD. Check the steps below if it is helpful.https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-CLEAN-Install-Windows-8-directly-from-Hard-/

Comment: @daidai I already tried those steps, which for some reason, do not work for an older (32 bit, x86) system.